# What is the correct way, FB Apps "permissions request" page

Tags: facebook, permissions

I did a test our facebook Apps in the "permissions request" page.

According to description of this site, 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step5

(A) correct 
    If the user decided to decline to authorize your app in the Login Dialog, they will instead be redirected to:

---

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?
 &error_reason=user_denied
 &error=access_denied
 &error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
 &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
 ~~~~~~
```

---

(B) However, Our results of the test(17/Oct/2012)

---

```
 &error_reason=user_denied
 &error=access_denied
 &error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
 &0=13504605426376027014824690496996#_=_
 ~~
```

---

There is difference between (A) and (B). 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($user) {

    $me = $fb->api('/me'); 
    } else {
$url =   "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
                ."client_id=app_idxxxxxxxxx&"
                ."redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/app_idxxxxxxxxx/&"
                ."scope=user_photos,publish_stream";
    echo "<script language=javascript>window.open('$url', '_parent', '')</script>";

        exit();
}
```